# onActivityResult em outra classe

Tags: android, classes, android-activity, android-camera

estou criando um app onde tenho varias chamadas da câmera, e gostaria de criar uma classe para chamar a câmera para utilizar no projeto , bom, a chamada da activity esta sendo feita com o activityforresult nesta classe, a foto e capturada, porem ao retornar a activity principal, onativityresult na captura o código

Main_Activity

```
 
TirarFotoPrincipal(context, IV_Clicado, String_Dados);
```

Camera_Class

```
public void TirarFotoPrincipal(final Context context, final ImageView imageView, final String Dados) {

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final String nome_foto = "foto_olho_" + lado_do_olho + "_" + id_animal_prontuario + "_principal.jpg";
                final String imagem = Constante.LOCALPATH + nome_foto;

                String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + nome_foto;

                File Nova_Foto = new File(path);
                File file = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder"), nome_foto);


                String CAMERA_FP_AUTHORITY = "com.example.john.oftalmovet.fileprovider";



                    fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            context,
                            CAMERA_FP_AUTHORITY,
                            Nova_Foto);



                Intent Intent_Camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                Intent_Camera.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Intent_Camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(Intent_Camera, codigo_for_result);
            }
        });


    }
```

esses dois códigos estão funcionado, porem estou com problemas em adicionar o onactivityresult,

tentei colocar na câmera class mas n retornou os dados, também tentei colocar na main activity mas não deu certo também

se eu colocar o código da câmera class direto na main_activity e chamar o onactivityresult com oq preciso fazer apos a captura da foto, funciona perfeitamente, porem sera re escrito em diversas outras activity

dês de já, agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Você pode capturar os valores que recebe em `onActivityResult` e enviar para outra `activity`?. Ex: `Intent intent = new Intent(context, another.class); intent.putExtra("key", intentDoActivityResult.getExtras());`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr entao nao tem uma maneira de utilizar o onactivityresult ? terei que criar uma outra intent para fazer isso?

Comment: O `onActivityResult´ só funcionará na `activity` que você invocou o `startActivityForResult`. O que seria essa classe "Camera" e porque será re-escrito em diversas outras `activity`? Se puder explicar...

Comment: @ValdeirPsr , a classe camera sera aberta em varias activities diferentes , mas os resultados dela devem voltar para a activity que chama a classe, desta maneira , quero usar essa classe para todos e nao precisarei refazer o codigo em cada activity

Comment: Você chamou o `super.onActivityResult(..)` dentro da sua `Main_Activity`?

Comment: @DanilodeOliveira nao fiz isso na main_activity

Comment: A pergunta esta bem escrota, mas deixa eu ver se entendi, vc esta tentando re-utilizar um codigo de abertura de camera? Se for isso vc pode declarar uma classe, extender ela de uma Activity de sua preferencia, implementar o metodo com modificador public ou protected, e na sua Main_Activity extender da Class que criou, e as demais é so chamar esse método, agora para pegar o retorno, basta reescrever o onActivityResult, e se vc remover o metodo SUPER do onActivityResul suas fragments não receberão os resultados caso vc faça chamadas startActivityForResult